# Facebook Api Check Access Token Without Hardcoding App Secret

Tags: facebook-graph-api, win-universal-app, webrequest

I'm building a manual login flow for my App which is integrating some facebook functionality. 
I need to check when the current access_token of the user will expire.
The API documentary says I should do this call:

GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?

input_token={token-to-inspect} &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}

So I did this in C#:

```
        Uri inspectAccessTokenUri = new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token="+access_token+"&"); //IDK which value should have the last parameter
        HttpWebRequest checkToken = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inspectAccessTokenUri);
        var response = await checkToken.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine(data);
```

The last parameter should be the app-token:

**BUT:** Of course I looked up how to get the app-token and facebook says:

> Note that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be
>   made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled.
>   It is important that your app secret is never shared with anyone.
>   Therefore, this API call should only be made using server-side code.
>   (Facebook Graph API Documentation 1.1.16)

So my question: Can I check the token without the app-token or hardcoding the app-secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app-token is expired you will get a facebook response error. And you can catch this exception to deal with the situation you want. In this way you don't need to make a request with your app secret.
You can also use fb-uwp sdk that contains AccessTokenData for authenticated users

Comment: Yep, I will do that. I chose to build a manual login-flow and not using a sdk.

Answer (score 1):

- App secret is usually used by the server-side app, we don't use it in our UWP app, it could be decompiled.
- Read the official doc about FB Graph [Debug-Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/debug_token), this can only be used when you debug your app, for example if you want to check the metadata about a given access token, after you publish your app, your code will not relay on it.
- In an UWP app, we use [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class to connect to OAuth providers such as Facebook, Flickr, Google, and Twitter. Maintenance is need during using OAuth connections. For example, expires information is included in the access token, when we use OAuth protocol for authentication and authorization, we need to refresh the access token after it expired.

Due to these conditions, you may reconsider what you can do in an UWP app and which API you should choose.